# Tornado/Python – How do I avoid this repetition?

Tags: python, tornado

I am new to Tornado, and I have this simplified code for the purposes of this question:

```
class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        error_message = None
        title = "Log in to your account"

        self.render("login.html", error_message=error_message, title=title)

    def post(self):
        #function and params excluded for brevity of question
        error_message = self.authenticate_user()
        title = "Log in to your account"

        self.render("login.html", error_message=error_message, title=title)
```

The `self.render("login.html", error_message=error_message, title = title)` as well as the title variable are repeated (seemingly unnecessarily) because otherwise, I get the error "Global variable 'title' or 'error_message' not defined," depending on whether I use `post` or `get` to render the page.

I have a different title for every page, and I was wondering how I can simply have one `title` variable and one `self.render("login.html"...)` per page handler (i.e., `LoginHandler`) that will work when either the get or post function is called. I don't like the verbatim repetition, but I am having trouble avoiding error messages when I don't do the same thing in both functions.

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid redeclaring the `title` and `error_message` variables by initiating them as class members. (I used the leading underscore `_` in the variable name to indicate that this value should be private and is only to be used in this class.)

```
class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        # Call the BaseHandler's __init__ function to initialize parent's members
        BaseHandler.__init__()
        self._title = "Log in to your account"

    def get(self):
        self.render("login.html", error_message=None, title=self._title)

    def post(self):
        self.render("login.html", error_message=self.authenticate_user(), title=self._title)
```

The added advantages of doing it this way is that you only need to change the `title` in one spot and you don't run the risk of getting a different title depending on whether the method was `get` or `post`.

NOTE: It appears that in `error_message` is not necessary - it's only being used in a single case. The `self.render()` calls do not receive the same parameters and therefore are both necessary.

Comment: This is great, thank you! Glad I wasn't doing something too off the mark.